# Where is dahdi_cfg called from on system boot?

Tags: dahdi

I install DAHDI on Debian stable (Buster) via module-assistant like this:

```
apt-get install dahdi dahdi-source module-assistant
module-assistant auto-install dahdi
```

I also create `/etc/dahdi/system.conf` and `/etc/dahdi/assigned-spans.conf`.

I cannot figure out who calls `dahdi_cfg` during system boot. I can confirm that it **does** get called by something, because if I remove `dahdi_cfg` and reboot, `echo` and `dahdi_echocan_oslec` modules are missing from `lsmod` (echo cancellation is specified in `system.conf`).

I found `/usr/share/dahdi/span_config.d/10-dahdi-cfg`, but I have no idea what may run this.

So, where is `dahdi_cfg` called from during system boot?

**UPDATE**

I found out that if `system.conf` is missing, echo cancellation modules are loaded anyways. Mandatory conditions are:

- presence of `dahdi_cfg`
- /etc/dahdi/assigned-spans.conf

**UPDATE2**

One more observation: if `/etc/dahdi/assigned-spans.conf` is removed and `options dahdi auto_assign_spans=1` is added to /etc/modprobe.d/dahdi.conf, echo cancellation modules are not loaded (system.conf is still removed). So it seems `auto_assign_spans=1` is not working.

---

Can anybody answer new questions in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's deal with `auto_assign_spans=1`:

Remove `auto_assign_spans=1`. Result: `/proc/dahdi/` is empty.
Use `auto_assign_spans=1`. Result: `/proc/dahdi/` is not empty.

So, this is the way how to check the effect of `auto_assign_spans=1`.

This is the example:

```
Span 1: WCTDM/0 "Wildcard TDM410P" (MASTER) 

       1 WCTDM/0/0 RED 
       2 WCTDM/0/1 
       3 WCTDM/0/2 
       4 WCTDM/0/3
```

Now run `dahdi_genconf system` and check `/proc/dahdi/1` again:

```
Span 1: WCTDM/0 "Wildcard TDM410P" (MASTER) 

   1 WCTDM/0/0 FXSKS RED 
   2 WCTDM/0/1 FXOKS 
   3 WCTDM/0/2 FXOKS 
   4 WCTDM/0/3 FXOKS
```

We have seen that `dahdi_genconf` messes with the span. **Is this a bug?**

Then run `dahdi_cfg` and check `/proc/dahdi/1` again:

```
Span 1: WCTDM/0 "Wildcard TDM410P" (MASTER) 

   1 WCTDM/0/0 FXSKS RED (EC: OSLEC - INACTIVE) 
   2 WCTDM/0/1 FXOKS (EC: OSLEC - INACTIVE) 
   3 WCTDM/0/2 FXOKS (EC: OSLEC - INACTIVE) 
   4 WCTDM/0/3 FXOKS (EC: OSLEC - INACTIVE)
```

Now we see that everything is properly configured.

---

Next, `dahdi_handle_device` is called by udev. It does nothing (because `auto_assign_spans=1` is used).

Then `dahdi_span_config` is called by udev. It does nothing also for the same reason.

And this is the interesting part: `dahdi_cfg` is not called if `auto_assign_spans=1` is used. **Is this a bug?**

### ------------------------------

On the contrary, if `auto_assign_spans=1` is not used, `dahdi_cfg` is called by `dahdi_span_config`.

This is a bit confusing. Why is it prohibited to run `dahdi_cfg` if `auto_assign_spans=1` is used? If we have only one card, this is perfectly acceptable. `auto_assign_spans=1` is even documented in dahdi-tools README as the use case for such scenario:

> Normally (with auto_assign_spans=1 in the module
>   dahdi, which is the default), when a device is discovered and loaded,
>   it registers with the DAHDI core and its spans automatically become
>   available. However if you have more than one device, you may be
>   interested to set explicit spans and channels numbers for them.

Is it safe to add `dahdi_cfg` to `dahdi_span_config` manually?

BTW, `system.conf` need not even be created - it is generated dynamically if it does not exist, but again, only if `auto_assign_spans=1` is not used.
If this deficiency is corrected somehow, the only thing needed to configure DAHDI would be just

```
echo options dahdi auto_assign_spans=1 >/etc/modprobe.d/dahdi.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following patch for `/lib/udev/rules.d/60-dahdi.rules`:

```
+SUBSYSTEM=="dahdi_spans", RUN+="/usr/sbin/dahdi_cfg"
 LABEL="dahdi_add_end"
```